# How to monitor system with `snort` and send emails about `alerts`

Tags: debian, logs, syslog, mail-command, snort

**PROBLEM:**

I have been configuring `snort` on my systems and would like to get emails from the systems if there are any alerts.

What I have tried is `swatch` but I can't find much documentation on it, can only find very basic and incomplete "how to's sites" and this [onnocenter.or.id/wik](http://onnocenter.or.id/wiki/index.php/SNORT:_email_alert)

I created a service with `systemd` and setup `swatch.conf` but it's not working:

swatchWATCH.service:

```
 1 [Unit]
 2 Description=Monitor Logfiles and send Mail reports
 3 After=syslog.target network.target
 4
 5 [Service]
 6 Type=simple
 7 ExecStart=/usr/bin/swatch --config-file=/home/kristjan/.swatchrc --input-record-separator="\n \n " --tail-file=/var/log/snort/alert --daemon
 8 Restart=always
 9 #--tail-file=/var/log/auth.log
10 #./swatch -c /usr/local/.swatchrc -input-record-separator="\n \n " -p="tail -f /var/log/snort/alert " -daemon
11 #-c This option specifies the location of the .swatchrc file.
12 #
13 #---input-record-separator With this command-line option you can specify the delimiting boundary for each alert. By default it is the newline character, \n.
14 #
15 #-p This option is used to read information outputted directly from a command. You can use it to monitor the output of a command for specific events.
16 #
17 #-t This option specifies the file to be monitored for security events.
18 #
19 #---daemon Append this switch to enable daemon mode. 
20
21 [Install]
22 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`.swatchrc`:

```
 1 watchfor /Priority \:1/
 2     echo=normal
 3     mail=myemailATTgmail.com, subject=Snort Security Alert!
 4
 5 watchfor /Priority \:2/
 6     echo=normal
 7     mail=mymailATTgmail.com, subject=Snort Security Alert!
 8
 9
```

I have also looked at `syslog-ng` but same I've only found incomplete how to's and it looks to be very complicated.

**SPECS:**

My systems are Debian Stretch 9.8 and `snort` is the from the repositories. I also have `logwatch` installed and configured on the servers.

I send mail on my systems like this:

```
mail -s '"Subject: auth: FAILED su for root\n\n$_\n"' somethingATTgmail.com
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I get mail(my servers are set up to send email) notifications from `snort`(How would you do it?)?

Where does `snort` log alerts(what file)?

Comment: @JimL. No mail is working fine it's not a complete command but is copied there to show my mail program

Comment: That subject line makes me nervous.  I'd simplify until you get it working: `mail -s "snort alert" you@example.com`.  You can fancy it up when you get more of the big picture working.  Sorry, I'm only here for the `mail-command` tag.  I'm not a snort user.  Don't the docs say where the logs go to?